# Getting 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request when tried to connect mongodb using node js in PCF platform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pcfdev

I have **mongodb** in **AWS EC2 instance**.

I am trying to connec to mongodb instance from nodejs server using **mongoClient**. My node application is deployed on PCF platform.

When i try to connect to mongodb
it throws an error "**502 Bad Gateway**:

Registered endpoint failed to handle the request". My node application is working fine, one the connection with mongodb is causing the problem.

```
conn_str += req.params.dbname;
mongoClient.connect(conn_str, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        res.end(err);
    } else {
        res.end(db);
    }
});
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I think It should be `conn_str += '/'+req.params.dbname`

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, but i have already assigned the value as var conn_str = 'mongodb://username:password@ipaddress:27017/'; and still it dosent work.

Comment: Where is your mongoDB deployed?

Comment: @Arun i think you are having problem in `auth` try not running mongodb in `monodb --auth` but simple `mongodb` command then change `conn_str` without auth info as 'mongodb://ipaddress:27017/` , this works in most cases

Comment: @sanjay mongodb is deployed in AWS Ec2 instance

Comment: @wrangler : perfect it worked without the auth info, but how can i make it working with auth info, just to make it secure. thanks

Comment: @Arun please refer this documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: @SanjayAchar : thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I had faced a similar issue while I was trying to connect to my mongo cluster which was deployed on Google Compute Engine. The below checklist helped me resolve the issue

1. Check if your firewall and make sure that the port 27017 is open for external requests
2. Check if your MongoDB is up and running (just do a curl localhost:27017 from terminal) if it's running you should get the protocol error
3. Check if your MongoDB is configured to accept requests from applications that is outside it's network (if you're running on different VPC) -- By default, MongoDB doesn't allow external requests

Comment: Hi Sanjay, thankyou for your response, I checked the points you have mentioned. i have commented out the bindip in mongodb conf file, so it should accept all the external request. and for the EC2 instance i have an inbound for all traffic at 0.0.0.0/0 just to make sure this is not causing the issue.